# Remove row from dataframe based on known row label but not value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is the output of a LinearRegression() call that looks something like this:

```
coeff_df = 
             Coefficient
pm  0.8297072586069981
sen 0.8199381072144118
tem 0.7483758123794492
no  0.2825715519743024
s_ref   -0.4376018493604922
ref -0.02338361622015777
```

I would like to remove the coefficients that I deem to be unimportant, e.g.:

```
coeff_df_abs = abs(coeff_df)
highestcoeff = coeff_df_abs.max()
lowestcoeff = coeff_df_abs.min()
if highestcoeff[0] / lowestcoeff[0] > 10
   #delete lowestcoeff from coeff_df
```

I can get a new dataframe that has nans (or .dropnans for just a 1x1 dataframe)

```
new_coeffs = coeff_df[coeff_df_abs==coeff_df_abs.min()]
#output
    Coefficient
pm25    
sen 
tem 
no  
s_ref   
ref -0.023383616220157777
```

How do I then remove the one non-nan cell from new_coeffs from the original dataframe coeff_df?

Note that I can't utilize the values of the dataframe cells because I'm really testing for closeness to 0 as opposed to > or < 0 and I don't know what cells are negative or positive.

Thanks!

edit: I'll add to say that the actual intent is to call a new linear regression using only the coeffs that passed my test so bonus points if I can get something that I can turn into a list to pass back into my X,y dataframes eg.

```
possible_Xvars = ['pm','sen','tem']
X = dataset[possible_xvars].values  #this already works in my code, just for clarity of ultimate goal
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I then remove the one non-nan cell from new_coeffs from the
>   original dataframe coeff_df?

Assuming that the first column is your index, you could simply use

```
coeff_df.drop(new_coeffs.index)
```

which is equivalent to

```
coeff_df.drop(labels=new_coeffs.index, axis='index')
```

where `labels` is a label name or a list of such and `axis` defines whether the specified labels occur in the index (rows) or the columns of the dataframe. See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

In general, using the index attribute may also be the answer to the second part of your question. The `index.tolist()` method generates a list with all existing label names in the dataframe. So, what you are looking for should be:

```
possible_Xvars = new_coeffs.index.tolist()
```